# Changed values are lost after returning from promise

Tags: protractor, es6-promise

I am doing E2E Test with protractor, using cucumber for test scenarios.
I face a strange problem: I lost the values I set inside of the promise.

What am I doing wrong?
My step-file.js:

```
var loggedUser = new User("dummyname", "dummyrole"); 

this.When(/^I click on a user name$/, function(){
      userelem.element(by.className('username')).getText().then(function (txt) {
        loggedUser.username = txt;
      });
});

this.Then(/^The username of the object "loggedUser" is set to a new value$/, function(){
    var answer = "dummyname" != loggedUser.username;
    assert.isOk(answer, "username is still dummyname!"); //this line fails since usrname is set back to dummyname again!
});
```

Comment: Maybe someone tells me why this post is getting downvoted instead of an answer? :( ?! Anything wrong about the description?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is you need to make each step definition return a promise, I write a simple code for you and it worked well.

`Make step definition return a promise is the key point`.

For Cucumber 2:

```
var { defineSupportCode } = require("cucumber");

defineSupportCode(function({ Given, When, Then }) {
    let title = 'test';

    Given(/^open npmjs.com$/, function() {
        browser.get("http://www.npmjs.com");
        return browser.getTitle().then(function(title1){
            title = title1;
            console.log('title: ' + title);
        });
    });

    Then(/^verify page title$/, function() {
        return expect(title).to.equal('npm');
    });
});
```

For Cucumber 1:

```
module.exports = function() {
    let title = 'test';

    this.Given(/^open npmjs.com$/, function() {
        browser.get("http://www.npmjs.com");
        return browser.getTitle().then(function(title1){
            title = title1;
            console.log('title: ' + title);
        });
    });

    this.Then(/^verify page title$/, function() {
        return expect(title).to.equal('npm');
    });
};
```

Comment: In cucumber ^2 there is a breaking change. If I upgrade cucumber I would have to adopt tausends lines of code. May be there is another solution for the problem than upgrading cucumber?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @yong for your suggestion on my first post (which I have deleted meanwhile). Finally I understood what you meant. Here is the solution:
(Instead of upgrading to cucumber 2,) I "return" the promise from within the "When-Step", so that protractor waits until it is fullfilled before it executes the next step-function:

```
var loggedUser = new User("dummyname", "dummyrole"); 

this.When(/^I click on a user name$/, function(){
      return userelem.element(by.className('username')).getText().then(function (txt) {
              loggedUser.username = txt;
      });
});
```

Now in the next step-functions, the username is the updated username.